# Trie, how deletions are managed at low level memory management and layout

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

When a key is deleted from the trie, it will free up space in the memory layout of the trie. This space may be in the middle of the trie. What are the memory management systems that allow such a gap to later be filled in, and how do they work?

Edit: I guess the answer here is that anyone can choose whatever memory management they want, and that the State only cares about the hashes being correct and does not care about how people do it at low level.